# jQuery link toggle not hiding divs

Tags: jquery

I have written some jQuery code to toggle divs. It's working, but I need it to immediately toggle the next div, which is not happening.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function() { 
       var id = $(this).attr('name');
       $('#tab' + id).slideToggle('slow');
       return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: We need more information.  can you include some html as well and explain which divs you want toggled?

Comment: I have given in the link http://goo.gl/juR6Vq

Comment: I saw the link but it's a lot easier for me if you just give me an example of the html so I don't have to digging through an entire page or site.

Comment: In the future, please try to provide more detail about your issue in the body of the question, rather than relying on external links. That way, the question is still useful to others if the external link changes, and it's easier for people to understand/help you even if the link doesn't change. This question quickly received flags for being spam, and I initially agreed with them.

Answer (score 9):

Add an additional class to each of the `tab<x>` element like

```
<div id="tab1" class="row tab" style="display: block;">
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $tabs = $('.tabs');    
    $('.nav-toggle').click(function() { 
        var id = $(this).attr('name');
        var $tab = $('#tab' + id).slideToggle('slow');
        $tabs.not($tab).hide();
        return false; 
    });
});
```

Comment: <div id="tab1" class="row tabs" style="display: block;"> -> tab to tabs then it will work